# How to remove sender name and sender email from the docusign email notification programmatically?

Tags: java, docusignapi, docusignconnect, e-signature

DocuSign sends an email to the signer, with the documents and if we don't mentions any email body, it just says please docusign document name, I wanted to know if we can remove sender details like

Sender name,
Sender email address,

Hello recipient name,

please docusign document name,

Thank you, sender name

Is there a possibility to remove sender name and sender email address at the beginning programatically without having to edit the resources file in the branding

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the email resource file. The only changes you can make from the API are the email subject and the blurb that shows below. But the title you're referring to at the top can only be modified by changing the resource file for the branding.